# Cannot set keybinding with 4 keys (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to change **move-to-workspace-up** keybinding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> combination but is just doesn't work. That's what I do:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>Up']"
```

When I change it back to combination of 3 keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>) it works fine. What is the problem I how can I fix it?